# Do `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_cond_wait` wait on the same queue?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I know that:

- If owner thread calls `pthread_mutex_unlock`, it will wake up a thread that is blocking on the mutex.
- If owner thread calls `pthread_cond_wait`, it will atomically release the mutex and wait.
- If owner thread wants to wake up one thread sleeping on its conditional variable, it will do `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`

Why do we need `pthread_cond_signal` if `pthread_mutex_unlock` itself can wake up those blocking threads?

Comment: When `pthread_cond_wait` blocks (that is needs to wait) it releases the mutex. In other words, `pthread_cond_wait` is not blocked on the mutex so unlocking the mutex has no affect on the thread calling `pthread_cond_wait`. In fact, it is recommended but not required for the `pthread_cond_signal` caller to lock the mutex. The  mutex is really needed to synchronise multiple threads that are blocked on the same conditional variable.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks. Does it mean `pthread_cond_wait` put caller in its conditional variable's waiting queue (other than mutex)?  Is it better to call `pthread_mutex_unlock` before `pthread_cond_signal`?

Comment: Yes to the first question. But I don't understand the second question. `pthread_cond_signal` itself does not lock the mutex. But if your code explicitly locks the mutex before calling signal then not only is it better but it is a must that it unlocks the mutex (usually after the signal but can even be before). Otherwise none of the waits will unblock. That is, an unlocked mutex is required but not sufficient to unblock `pthread_cond_wait`.

Comment: @kaylum You mentioned " (usually after the signal but can even be before)". That is what I'm asking for. Which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_cond_wait()` blocks the calling thread until specific condition is signaled. This routine should be called while mutex is locked and it will automatically release the mutex while it waits.  After a signal is received, the thread will be awakened and mutex will again be owned by the thread. Programmer needs to take care of unlocking mutex when thread is finished with it.

`pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex)` is used when thread has completed its use of protected data.  When the programmer wants to unlock the mutex without any condition this should be used.

`pthread_cond_signal (condition)` is used to signal (or wake up) another thread which is waiting on the condition variable. This should be used only when one thread is to be woken from a blocking wait state. If more than one thread should be woken from blocking wait state than `pthread_cond_broadcast(condition)`  should be used instead.

> Why do we need `pthread_cond_signal` if `pthread_mutex_unlock` itself can
> wake up those blocking threads?

Look at this code to understand your question :

```c
void foo ()
{
    for (i=0; i < TCOUNT; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
        count++;
        /*
        Check the value of count and signal waiting thread when condition is
        reached. Note that this occurs while mutex is locked.
        */
        if (count == COUNT_LIMIT) {
            pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
            printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d Threshold reached.\n", my_id, count);
        }
        printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d, unlocking mutex\n", my_id, count);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    }
    /* Do some "work" so threads can alternate on mutex lock */
    sleep(1);
}

void done () 
{
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

For `pthread_mutex_lock()` :

```c
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
str.mul *= mymul;  /* Do some process on protected data */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

In the first code, the mutex is unlocked by `pthread_cond_signal()` if the condition is satisfied.
In the second code, there is no condition directly mutex will be unlocked. In this type of case you can use `pthread_mutex_unlock()`

One more thing, sometimes `pthread_cond_signal()` fails to unlock the mutex; that is why mutex must be unlocked to complete the routine.

Comment: This is not what I'm asking for.

Comment: Sorry I have only looked at your second question forgot to answer first one. I have updated answer for both of your question .I hope this is what you are asking for.